# Filter using NSPredicate of Array of Dictionary within dictionary in iOS

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

```
Rewards -- Array
   Normal Reward -- Object
     Offer -- Dictionary
       Meta -- Dictionary
         rewardId -- String
   Normal Reward -- Object
     Offer -- Dictionary
       Meta -- Dictionary
         rewardId -- String
```

I have the above hierarchy out of which I have to match a particular **rewardId** for a value. How can I achieve that using NSPredicate.

Comment: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.nameOfOfferProperty.nameOfMetaKey.rewardId == %@", myRewardIdToMatch]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This predicate should do the trick:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.nameOfOfferProperty.nameOfMetaKey.nameOfRewardIdKey == %@", myRewardIdToMatch]
```

I explicitly named the path to go according to your needs.

With Sample code (this way you can see what name to use if needed):

```
NSMutableArray *rewards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
    NSString *rewardId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rewardID %@", (i%2 == 0)?@"Target":@"NonWanted"];
    NSString *otherMetaValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"otherMetaValue-%ld", i];
    NSString *otherOfferValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"otherOfferValue-%ld", i];
    NSDictionary *anOfferDict = @{@"meta": @{@"rewardId": rewardId,
                                             @"otherMetaKey": otherMetaValue},
                                  @"otherOfferKey": otherOfferValue};
    Reward *aReward = [[Reward alloc] initWithOfferDict:anOfferDict andIntValue:i];
    [rewards addObject:aReward];
}
NSLog(@"Rewards: %@", rewards);
NSString * myRewardIdToMatch = @"rewardID Target";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.offer.meta.rewardId == %@", myRewardIdToMatch];


NSArray *filteredRewards = [rewards filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"FilteredRewards: %@", filteredRewards);
```

And

```
@implementation Reward
-(id)initWithOfferDict:(NSDictionary *)dict andIntValue:(NSUInteger)intV
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _offer = dict;
        _intV = intV;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Overriding `description` can be helpful and make it clear if it worked:

```
-(NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@ %p> with IntValue: %ld and rewardID:\n%@", [self class], self, _intV,  _offer[@"meta"][@"rewardId"]];

}
@end
```

Output:

```
$> Rewards: (
    "<Reward 0x60000022ce80> with IntValue: 0 and rewardID: rewardID Target",
    "<Reward 0x60000022ce00> with IntValue: 1 and rewardID: rewardID NonWanted",
    "<Reward 0x60000022cf80> with IntValue: 2 and rewardID: rewardID Target",
    "<Reward 0x60000022cea0> with IntValue: 3 and rewardID: rewardID NonWanted",
    "<Reward 0x60000022cf20> with IntValue: 4 and rewardID: rewardID Target",
    "<Reward 0x60000022ce40> with IntValue: 5 and rewardID: rewardID NonWanted",
    "<Reward 0x60000022cfa0> with IntValue: 6 and rewardID: rewardID Target",
    "<Reward 0x60000022cfc0> with IntValue: 7 and rewardID: rewardID NonWanted",
    "<Reward 0x60000022ce60> with IntValue: 8 and rewardID: rewardID Target",
    "<Reward 0x60000022cec0> with IntValue: 9 and rewardID: rewardID NonWanted"
)
$> FilteredRewards: (
    "<Reward 0x60000022ce80> with IntValue: 0 and rewardID: rewardID Target",
    "<Reward 0x60000022cf80> with IntValue: 2 and rewardID: rewardID Target",
    "<Reward 0x60000022cf20> with IntValue: 4 and rewardID: rewardID Target",
    "<Reward 0x60000022cfa0> with IntValue: 6 and rewardID: rewardID Target",
    "<Reward 0x60000022ce60> with IntValue: 8 and rewardID: rewardID Target"
)
```

Comment: Do you mind telling why? Is there a crash? A crash log then? What did you use? Does your objects looks like mine? DIfferent? What did you try? You can see that my code is working, so what's different between mine and yours?